# MVC Core - Return to previous page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to return to previous page on `controller` action in ASP.Net Core?

**Example:**

Let's say we have the following `controllers`:

- `HomeController` with action `Index()` returning `View()`
- `BlogPostController` with action `BlogPosts()` returning `View(model)`
- `PostController` (the same) with action `BlogPost(int postId)` returning `View(model)`

There is also a button on the `_Layout`, (so it is available in all other `Views`) which on click goes to action `DoSomething()` in `GlobalController`. As calling `DoSomething()` is available from all `Views` in my application, I want it to just create a cookie and reload the previous page, without having to redirect to an exact action.

To be more specific: if I call `DoSomething()` while on `http://mysite/index` I want it to create a cookie and go back to `http://mysite/index` and reload it. Same goes for the situation when I'm on `http://mysite/BlogPost?postId=13`.

Is this possible in ASP.Net Core 2.0? If yes, how to achieve it?

Comment: Not sure about using cookies/controller actions but i have found it is possible to use JS -     
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</a>

Comment: Saw that too, but I think it would go back on click instead of doing actions from my `DoSomething()` method from controller and I need them to be done first.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .Net Core 3.1 this line inside your controller method will redirect to the previous page
`return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]);`

That is all you need....

Answer (score 2):

The problem with history.go(-1) is that if you have just submitted a form it will attempt to submit the form again...

Maybe you could add a global action filter that checks the referer using something like:

```
Request.Headers["Referer"]
```

Then store the referring url in a cookie like you suggest but only after checking that it was a GET and not a post?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's correct approach, but I have "hacked" that by:

1. Changing my controller action return type to `void`
2. Setting `Response.StatusCode = 204` in my controller action (204 is a code for success without additional content)
3. Calling my action from the View via ajax, with using `location.reload()` on success

If you have any comments regarding that solution, please let me know. I'm not sure if that's the approach to follow, so I'd be glad to hear from more experienced web devs.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[HttpGet] // This isn't required
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // load object and return in view
    ViewModel viewModel = Load(id);

    // get the previous url and store it with view model
    viewModel.PreviousUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Attempt to save the posted object if it works, return index if not return the Edit view again

    bool success = Save(viewModel);
    if (success)
    {
        return Redirect(viewModel.PreviousUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("There was an error");
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

The `BeginForm` method for your view doesn't need to use this return URL either, you should be able to get away with:

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="PreviousUrl" value="@Model.PreviousUrl" />
}
```